# Spring Data Mongo: query by example(QBE) does not work for records without "_class" property

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

If I have records in mongoDb without "_class" property, query by example does not work. My database is populated by third-party non-java microservice, by the way.
Example:

```
{
  "_id":"5ec3f00d98326d4c0ead815f",
  "first_name":"firstName",
  "last_name":"lastName"
}
```

Then `MongoRepository.findAll(Example<S> example)` is not able to find that record. If I add correct "_class" field manually, all works as expected.

Has someone solved this issue?
Spring Data mongo v.3.0.0.RC1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is UntypedExampleMatcher that must be used in this case:

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = UntypedExampleMatcher.matching()
        .withIgnoreNullValues()
        .withIgnoreCase();
Entity probe = ...

Example<Entity> entityExample = Example.of(probe, matcher);
entityRepo.findAll(entityExample);
```

But this approach does not work by some reason. It is very long-running, and ends with exception at the end.

**UPDATE:**
Because of incorrect "probe", my request tried to fetch from DB thousands of records, therefore it ended up with exception. After fixing it, search with QBE approach works as a charm.